# Can an odd number of stripes in RAID can affect tempdb performance if I have an even number of data files in tempdb?

Tags: sql-server, tempdb

This is out of curiosity: since it is recommended to configure tempdb data files in an even number of sets so that it can get aligned with NUMA nodes evenly, I just wanted to know if it is the case for RAID configuration as well.

If I use an odd number of stripes in my RAID configuration (for example 5 stripes in RAID 0, I know it is not redundant but just for the sake of simplicity), and if I have 8 tempdb data files, would it affect performance considerably if I had an even number of stripes, maybe 4?

Answer (score 0):

Number of disks in a RAID directly affect the disk subsystem performance.

A 5 disk RAID 0 will potentially perform 25% better then a 4 disk RAID 0.

All tempdb files will be striped across all disks in a RAID 0.